# How to instantiate a Stream.Builder class in clojure? (using java 9)

Tags: clojure

I'm following this example to initiate a Stream.Builder:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.stream/Stream.Builder/Stream.Builder.build_.htm

```
(def b (doto (Stream/builder)
          (.accept "a")
          (.accept "b")
          (.accept "c")
          (.accept "d")
          (.accept "e")))
```

However, I'm getting this:

```
Unhandled java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
 Method
 java.util.stream.Stream.builder()Ljava/util/stream/Stream$Builder;
 must be InterfaceMethodref constant
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: String or Stream builder? -> I'm following this example to initiate a String.Builder:

Comment: Stream.Builder. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Also did you check your Stream class path? (import java.util.stream.Stream) I have no problems

Comment: I'm using java 9. I'll try java 8

Comment: Yeah try that I'm using java and clojure 8

Comment: yes. java 8 works for me. It'll be useful to know how to get it going with java 9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167881/discussion-between-zcaudate-and-ertugrul-cetin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick research led me to this issue:
https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2284

so the workaround is as mentioned there:

```
(import 'java.util.stream.Stream)

(defmacro interface-static-call
  [sym & argtypes]
  `(let [m# (.getMethod ~(symbol (namespace sym))
                        ~(name sym)
                        (into-array Class ~argtypes))]
     (fn [& args#]
       (.invoke m# nil (to-array args#)))))

(doto ((interface-static-call Stream/builder))
  (.accept "a")
  (.accept "b")
  (.accept "c")
  (.accept "d")
  (.accept "e"))

;;=> #object[java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl 0x121300ed "java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl@121300ed"]
```

works for me on java 9

so i guess we should wait for a fix in clojure.

Answer (score 1):

Very helpful, thanks, for those of us stuck on Clojure 8 but needing to use a Java newer than 1.8.

For what it's worth, the macro in the answer above won't work if `argtypes` is not empty, because the macro as written constructs an unquoted list of classes as the third parameter to .getMethod, and Clojure tries to invoke the first class in the list as an IFn.  I needed to redefine the macro as:

```
(defmacro interface-static-call
  [sym & argtypes]
  `(let [m# (.getMethod ~(symbol (namespace sym))
                        ~(name sym)
                        (into-array Class ~(into [] argtypes)))]
     (fn [& args#]
       (.invoke m# nil (to-array args#)))))
```